# How to prevent badly cut words in LaTeX?

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

Here is the thought. I wish if there is any package or syntax in LaTeX that makes any arbitrary `\documentclass` to cut words as less as possible? I mean for the sake of sentences at the end in a two-columned document class, I faced this so often that I face words got cut which makes the text so ugly.

Comment: You mean prevent hyphenation?

Comment: @HarishKumar right.

Comment: You can use `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` or just put `\hyphenpenalty=10000\exhyphenpenalty=10000` in the preamble. It would be better to provide some MWE so that specific advice can be given.

Comment: @HarishKumar I just want a reasonable hyphenation. currently, in a two page column I got like 50% of all sentences to be hyphenated.

Comment: OK, in that case add `\usepackage{microtype}` in the pramble (say just before `\begin{document}` and you will see the change. Or use something like `\hyphenpenalty=3000\exhyphenpenalty=3000` just before `\begin{document}` adjust the 3000 accordingly. 10000 is the maximum where no hyphenation takes place. You have to reduce the value as suitable.

Comment: 1) Ugly is not the same as wrong. As a non native english speaker I must say that english hypenation always looks strange. However latex hyphenation is usually correct. 2) You can use the command `\hyphenation{multi-disci-pli-na-ry}` to split certain words differently. 3) You can turn off hyphenation (like other answers).

Comment: @alfC I'm not sure I agree.  I usually want to produce a beautiful document.  In that case, "ugly" is wrong.  And there are times where LaTeX, for all that it does right, can overhyphenate (even for this native speaker).  If 50 percent of the sentences (lines?) are getting hyphenated, I'd say that's excessive.   Hence the beauty of LaTeX in that it allows us to change penalties for less ugly results.  :)

Comment: @HarishKumar 3000 looks somehow nice. hope it does not disappoint me afterward.

Comment: @A.Ellett, preaching to the choir here. I am the first the *disable* hyphenation when things get ugly. I am not saying that visually ugly hyphenation should be tolerated. What I am saying is that it is purely a matter of taste, usually the concrete hyphenation is strange/ugly but correct.

Comment: There is also \sloppy

Comment: @JohnKormylo but did not work as it was not in the latex version im using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the hyphenation penalty.

```
\hyphenpenalty=10000 removes the hyphenation completely.
```

Instead you can set it to your required tolerance by decreasing the number from 10000 to any other number.

Comment: where should I place this syntax?

Comment: before the beginning of the document

Comment: also I would like to know what would be a reasonable value for this hyphenation? because if remove completely, it will exceed the column boundary and if in default, too much of it.

Comment: Try using \raggedright command at the preamble and check if you would like that output.

Comment: you mean that I exchange the `\hyphenpenalty=10000` with `\raggedright`? well that got much uglier. to make it more clear, I wish something like `Justify Low` that MS Word provides.

Comment: Yes, use raggedright instead of hyphenpenalty. Check if you like the output!

Comment: well, that got much uglier. Oo. but by adjusting the value to 3000 it looks fine now. wish stays stable.

Answer (score 2):

I found these lines which prevent LaTeX from hyphenation, but also keeps the justification so the text won't look ugly or will have different line lengths.

```
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
```

Source: [Sumanta’s WeBlog](https://sumanta679.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/latex-justify-without-hyphenation/)